# static reference to the non-static method getBaseContext()

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

Hi can anybody help my with error: 
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method `getBaseContext()` from the type ContextWrapper in line:

```
PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 
                0, result_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

at code:

```
public static NotificationManager notificationManager;
    public static final int NOTIF_ID = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jajko);

        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
        play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butStart);
        miekko = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butMiekko);
        srednio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butSrednio);
        twardo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.butTwardo);

        miekko.setOnClickListener(this);
        srednio.setOnClickListener(this);
        twardo.setOnClickListener(this);
        play.setOnClickListener(this);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(Jajko.this, R.raw.alarm);

        showNotification(this);

    }

    public static void showNotification(Context context) {
        final Intent result_intent = new Intent(context, Jajko.class);

        result_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        /*TaskStackBuilder stack_builder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stack_builder.addParentStack(Jajko.class);
        stack_builder.addNextIntent(result_intent);

        PendingIntent pending_intent = stack_builder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);*/
        PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(), 
                0, result_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context);

        Resources res = context.getResources();
        builder.setContentIntent(pending_intent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setLargeIcon(
                        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.icon))
                .setTicker("Egg Timer").setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(false).setContentTitle("Egg Timer")
                .setContentInfo("").setContentText("");
        Notification n = builder.build();
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, n);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to use:

```
PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 
            0, result_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `showNotification` is a `static` method, yet you need to call `getBaseContext()` to provide a context. Since that is not a `static` method, you cannot call it from one. Get rid of the `static` modifier for `showNotification`.